# Yii2 Making 2 columns layout

Tags: google-maps-api-3, yii2

i am trying to make my Yii2 application work in two columns.

First column: this will be Google Map Api v3 map object that will be controlled by other active site pages or options. This will be done with java script.

Second column: main content that will be updated using ajax. This will also control map.

This 2 column layout is not always needed. There will be some pages that i need standard 1 column layout (There will be no map then).

What is a better way to implement my needs? Should i use more than one layout file? How should it be done use couple of layout files?

Maybe there is any other way to do this? The main reason i want to implement this situation is because of google map reloading. It takes some time. Maybe if there is something that keeps map from reloading it would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a secondary layout that you want to use it in certain views and call it in the action :

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller
{
public $layout = 'column2';

// ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, what abau content? Only one column will be "content" for example the second one with all custom ajax loaded data. In this way the first column "map" should be defined staticly inside layout file. Am i right?